# Add product to cart programmatically with file type custom options

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I am trying to add products to cart programmatically having custom options of type file. Basically, there is a separate interface for some products in the shop where customer can customize the image being ordered. It's working with some external API which saves the final image on server and returns the path on the basis of which I'm going to add that into the custom option of product.

What I am trying to do is add that image into the custom option of product. Tried several methods but no success. Found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49207/how-to-add-file-type-custom-option-in-cart-page-programatically) question but no answer there.

This is what I have tried so far, but it keeps giving me error that required options is missing.(That image option is required)

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir();
$product_id = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$params = array(
    'product' => $product_id,
    'qty' => 1,
    'options_1_file_action' => array(
    1 => array(
        'quote_path' => $image,
        'secret_key' => substr(md5(file_get_contents($path . DS . $image)), 0, 20)),
        )
    );
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Also found this piece somewhere, but it depends upon FILES variable, so can't use it as there is no post from front.

```
$product_id = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$params = array(
    'product' => $product_id,
    'qty' => 1,
    'options_1_file_action' => 'save_new',
    'options_1_file' => array(
        'name' => $image,
        'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'tmp_name' => $image
    )
);
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: what is the value of the $image?

Comment: $image variable contains Magento's base directory relative path to the image file, it is what I am currently able to pass when adding product to the cart.

Comment: it does not work on magento 1.9.2.1 please help.

Comment: @Sazzad, It doesn't work in any Magento version. I haven't been able to find the solution for this one yet, and the project seems to be on hold as well. I'll try to figure it out when I resume that.

Comment: @Prateek any luck?

Comment: @Haris, No, I seem to have forgotten this issue, as project was put on hold, and haven't resumed since. I'll definitely try this on my own and post my findings here. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: @Prateek any update on this for M2?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1112);

$paramater = array('product' => '1112',
                    'qty' => '12',
                    'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(),
                    'options' => array('option_id'=>'sub_option_id')
            );       

$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($paramater);
$cart->addProduct($product, $request);
$cart->save();
```

If custom option is not required for this product that time this code will use. Otherwise, you change the base file of magento

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_File` (*app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php* this is where you want to look at how your option parameters are being processed I believe) `validateUserValue` tries to verify the file has been uploaded, however, it will ignore that if you `setSkipCheckRequiredOption()` on the `$product`.

```
    // Process new uploaded file
    try {
        $this->_validateUploadedFile();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($this->getSkipCheckRequiredOption()) {
            $this->setUserValue(null);
            return $this;
        } else {
            Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So modifying the second example from your question

```
$product_id = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$params = array(
    'product' => $product_id,
    'qty' => 1,
    'options_1_file_action' => 'save_new',
    'options_1_file' => array(
        'name' => $image,
        'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'tmp_name' => $image
    )
);

//--------------------------------------------------------
// Bypass uploaded image validation on the new file option
//--------------------------------------------------------
$product->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);

$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

That should get you past the validation against the `$_FILES` array, but I'm not sure it will 100% solve your problem.

Comment: Any justification for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the custom upload is as follows,

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('custom/index/uploadImage'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" type="file" name="options_5_file" id="file-upload-po" class="required-entry"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" id="addimage">
</form>
```

Then by using following way you can add to cart the product with the custom option (file) ,

```
public function uploadImageAction(){        
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(8);


    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
    $cart->init();

    $_product->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);

    $cart->addProduct($_product ,
            array(  'product_id' => 8,
                    'qty' => 1,
                    'options_5_file_action' => 'save_new'

                 ));

    $cart->save();

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

    $quote_itemID = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
               ->getQuote()
               ->getItemsCollection()
               ->getLastItem()
                ;
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart/configure/id/'.$quote_itemID->getId());}
```

Note that "options_5_file" is actual custom option field of type image in product.

Answer (score 0):

For M2 (Magento2.4.2), the following worked for me:
Suppose your form file upload html looks like below : (Loaded with core function)

```
<div class="control" id="input-box-options_22_file">
        <input type="file" name="options_22_file" id="options_22_file" class="product-custom-option required" aria-required="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="options_22_file_action" value="save_new" aria-required="true">
</div>
```

Then on your form submit you need an ajax request as well since Magento send binary of the file with params, but if you send it without ajax, probably only file name will be passed. To do ajax:

```
$('#addCart').on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         url: config.addCartUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
         cache: false,
    processData:false,
    });
        
    }));
```

In your addToCart.php you can traverse the options and if found with file you can do following:

```
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o)
      {
       foreach ($o->getValues() as $value)
              {
                  //do traversing for other option types
               }   
       if($o->getType() == "file")
            {
              $params['options_'.$o->getOptionId().'_file_action'] = 
              $postParams['options_'.$o->getOptionId().'_file_action'];
            }
               //$postParams is params from form submitted
     }
       $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
//don't forget to append other required params for add to cart
```

This will add to cart products with custom option type "file" without issues hopefully.